# Упростить/оптимизировать множественные условия Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, if

есть у меня вот такая вот таблица

[image: https://imgur.com/8t5hHzx.png]

Нужно по номеру месяца присвоить значение, думаю всё очевидно, но глядя вот на это:
[image: https://imgur.com/d9tTom5.png]

Мне хочется опрометью броситься куда угодно из этого времени. Есть ли идеи, как данное можно оптимизировать? У меня возникали мысли с кортежами и тд, но не могу придумать реализацию.
Извините, если подобное уже было или всё слишком очевидно. Надеюсь на вашу поддержку и отзывчивость!

Comment: Код кодом, а не картинками.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да и создание словаря тоже можно упростить, не вбивая вручную ключи, а только перечислив значения из таблицы им соответствующие, если точно известно, какие будут значения ключей (от 1 и далее в данном случае):

```
d = {k:v for k,v in enumerate([0.18, 0.32, 0.45], 1)}
print(d)
```

Вывод:

```
{1: 0.18, 2: 0.32, 3: 0.45}
```

Answer (score 1):

сделайте в виде словаря:

```
prices = {1: 0.18, 2: 0.32, 3: 0.45}

print(prices[2])
```

можно и в виде обычного списка, но тут уж немного неочевидно и можно допустить какую-нибудь ошибку

```
prices = [0.18, 0.32, 0.45]

print(prices[2 - 1])
```

Comment: да, спасибо, вариант с словарем - отличный !!
Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @Игорь, на будущее, пожалуйста, код и данные в своем вопросе представляйте в воспроизводимом формате - в виде текста, а не в виде скриншотов.

Comment: Хорошо, приношу извинения за неудобства. Буду знать!